# aligned images?

Tags: minipage, circuitikz

I need to put these two images aligned on the same line.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,4) to [sV,l2^=$V_i$ and {$220V\ $}{$10KHz$}](0,0)
      (0,4) to [R,l=$R_1$,a={3.456}{$\Omega$}] (4,4)
            to [C,l2^={$C_1$ and $1 \mu F$}] (4,0) -- (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Circuito RC}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{5mm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,4) to [sV,l2^=$V_i$ and {$220V$}{$10KHz$}](0,0)
      (0,4) to [R,l=$R_1$,a={2893,155}{$\Omega$}](4,4)
            to [L,l2^=$L_1$ and $10 mH$] (4,0)--(0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Circuito RL}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}
```

[image]

thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem is that `0.5\linewidth` + 5mm +`0.5\linewidth` is bigger than the line width, so your line is broken...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,4) to [sV,l2^=$V_i$ and {$220V\ $}{$10KHz$}](0,0)
      (0,4) to [R,l=$R_1$,a={3.456}{$\Omega$}] (4,4)
            to [C,l2^={$C_1$ and $1 \mu F$}] (4,0) -- (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Circuito RC}
\end{minipage}
\hspace*{5mm}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,4) to [sV,l2^=$V_i$ and {$220V$}{$10KHz$}](0,0)
      (0,4) to [R,l=$R_1$,a={2893,155}{$\Omega$}](4,4)
            to [L,l2^=$L_1$ and $10 mH$] (4,0)--(0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Circuito RL}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

You have two minipages that fill half of the text width, so you don't want space between them.

I also used `siunitx` in order to typeset measures according to the standards. For instance, the symbol for kiloHertz should be “kHz”, with a lowercase “k”; the unit symbols should always be upright. Also you see that you can type in the number with either the comma or the period for the decimal part and the output will be consistent. You can use the comma for the decimal separator by adding

```latex
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
```

in your document preamble.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,4) to [sV,l2^=$V_i$ and \SI{220}{\volt} \SI{10}{\kilo\hertz}](0,0)
      (0,4) to [R,l=$R_1$,a=\SI{3.456}{\ohm}] (4,4)
            to [C,l2^=$C_1$ and \SI{1}{\micro\farad}] (4,0) -- (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Circuito RC}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,4) to [sV,l2^=$V_i$ and \SI{220}{\volt} \SI{10}{\kilo\hertz}](0,0)
      (0,4) to [R,l=$R_1$,a=\SI{2893,155}{\ohm}](4,4)
            to [L,l2^=$L_1$ and \SI{10}{\milli\henry}] (4,0)--(0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\caption{Circuito RL}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]